# FileMaker Divide by Zero Error

Tags: filemaker

I have a Calculation field in my Results table that will calculate the coursework_percent based on a student's submission of classwork, homework, quiz, project and participation. The code for the Calculation field is this:

```
Sum (  Coursework_Results_Classwork::mark ) / If ( Sum ( Coursework_CR_Classwork::max_mark )  ≠ 0 ; Sum ( Coursework_CR_Classwork::max_mark ) - Sum ( Coursework_Results_Classwork::reduce_max ) ; 1 ) * Coursework_Weighting::classwork_w
+
Sum ( Coursework_Results_Homework::mark ) / If ( Sum ( Coursework_CR_Homework::max_mark ) ≠ 0 ; Sum ( Coursework_CR_Homework::max_mark ) - Sum ( Coursework_Results_Homework::reduce_max ) ; 1 ) * Coursework_Weighting::homework_w
+
Sum ( Coursework_Results_Quiz::mark ) / If ( Sum ( Coursework_CR_Quiz::max_mark ) ≠ 0 ;  Sum ( Coursework_CR_Quiz::max_mark ) - Sum ( Coursework_Results_Quiz::reduce_max ) ; 1 ) * Coursework_Weighting::quiz_w
+
Sum ( Coursework_Results_Project::mark ) / If ( Sum ( Coursework_CR_Project::max_mark ) ≠ 0  ; Sum ( Coursework_CR_Project::max_mark ) - Sum ( Coursework_Results_Project::reduce_max ) ; 1 ) * Coursework_Weighting::project_w
+
Sum ( Coursework_Results_Participation::mark ) / If ( Sum ( Coursework_CR_Participation::max_mark ) ≠ 0 ; Sum ( Coursework_CR_Participation::max_mark ) - Sum ( Coursework_Results_Participation::reduce_max ) ) * Coursework_Weighting::participation_w
```

The idea behind the code is this:
If a student did not submit a coursework due to valid reason, he should not be penalised. Hence, his maximum mark should be adjusted accordingly. I used `reduce_max` to reduce his otherwise maximum possible score.

My bug is this:
If a particular category (e.g. homework) has only 1 assignment and the student did not submit with valid reason(hence an empty field), the calculated field will have a `division by zero error`. I cannot use a `zero` because `zero` is used for non-submission without valid reason. I suspect that the bug lies in my `If` condition testing for `≠ 0`. An empty field is not considered a `zero`.

Can someone help me out? Thanks.

I amended pft's answer to solve my problem. The bug was not really due to empty field. Instead, it occurs when I use `reduce_max` such that the maximum of the coursework becomes zero. My solution is this:

```
Let ([
sumOfClasswork = Sum (  Coursework_Results_Classwork::mark );
sumOfHomework = Sum (  Coursework_Results_Homework::mark );
sumOfQuiz = Sum (  Coursework_Results_Quiz::mark );
sumOfProject = Sum (  Coursework_Results_Project::mark );
sumOfParticipation = Sum (  Coursework_Results_Participation::mark );

classworkMax = Sum ( Coursework_CR_Classwork::max_mark );
homeworkMax = Sum ( Coursework_CR_Homework::max_mark );
quizMax = Sum ( Coursework_CR_Quiz::max_mark );
projectMax = Sum ( Coursework_CR_Project::max_mark );
participationMax = Sum ( Coursework_CR_Participation::max_mark );

classworkReductions = Sum ( Coursework_Results_Classwork::reduce_max );
homeworkReductions = Sum ( Coursework_Results_Homework::reduce_max );
quizReductions = Sum ( Coursework_Results_Quiz::reduce_max );
projectReductions = Sum ( Coursework_Results_Project::reduce_max );
participationReductions = Sum ( Coursework_Results_Participation::reduce_max );

// if coursework maximum after reduction is zero, 1 is returned to avoid a division by zero error
classworkRedMax = If ( classworkMax - classworkReductions <> 0 ; classworkMax - classworkReductions ; 1 );
homeworkRedMax = If ( homeworkMax - homeworkReductions <> 0 ; homeworkMax - homeworkReductions ; 1 );
quizRedMax = If ( quizMax - quizReductions <> 0 ; quizMax - quizReductions ; 1 );
projectRedMax = If ( projectMax - projectReductions <> 0 ; projectMax - projectReductions ; 1 );
participationRedMax = If ( participationMax - participationReductions <> 0 ; participationMax - participationReductions ; 1 );

classworkWeight = Coursework_Weighting::classwork_w;
homeworkWeight = Coursework_Weighting::homework_w;
quizWeight = Coursework_Weighting::quiz_w;
projectWeight = Coursework_Weighting::project_w;
participationWeight = Coursework_Weighting::participation_w
];
// finally the computation of coursework ;)
sumOfClasswork / classworkRedMax * classworkWeight
+ 
sumOfHomework / homeworkRedMax * homeworkWeight
+
sumOfQuiz / quizRedMax * quizWeight
+
sumOfProject / projectRedMax * projectWeight
+
sumOfParticipation / participationRedMax * participationWeight
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `IsEmpty` function should help you out here. If I understand your intention correctly, you could use this code segment:

```
Let ([
    sumOfMarks = Sum (  Coursework_Results_Classwork::mark );
    sumOfMaxs = Sum ( Coursework_CR_Classwork::max_mark );
    sumOfReductions = Sum ( Coursework_Results_Classwork::reduce_max );
    firstMax = Coursework_CR_Classwork::max_mark;
    theWeight = Coursework_Weighting::classwork_w
];
    Case (
       // The case where the student has at least one valid,
       // positively-scored assignment
       sumOfMaxs > 0 ; sumOfMarks / (sumOfMaxs - sumOfReductions) ;

       // The case where there is only one related record for max_mark
       // and it is empty
       IsEmpty ( firstMax ) ; 1

    ) * theWeight
)
```